# Auto width for nav li tags

Tags: html, css, size, width, nav

I am trying to make my nav I am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my navI am trying to make my nav

```
<div class="headercss">class="header">

    <div class="headerlogo">class="header">

    </div>


</div>

/* BODY */

body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
}


/* 1. HEADER */

.headercssheader {
    width: auto;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.headerlogoheader {
    width: 980px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}

.nav {
    width: 980px;
    height: 70px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -490px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give width in % according to number of your items in list.

```
ul{ list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this `CSS` to your `ul` tag:

```
display:table;
table-layout: fixed;
```

and this to your `li` CSS:

```
display: table-cell;
```

Should work :)

Comment: BTW is the ul tag acting as a horizontal navbar? If yes, I will edit the answer/

Comment: Is it a horizontal navbar? The code is different for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use display: flex

```
.nav ul {
  display: flex;
}
.nav li {
  flex: 1;
}
```